# How to import service file (.srv) in a python node?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to import .srv file from another package into my python node. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342155/how-to-import-service-file-(.srv)-in-a-python-node?/) by [ehsan_amp](https://answers.ros.org/users/49314/ehsan_amp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-21**:
Can you specify what you already tried, what is not working (and provide the resulting error messages) please ? There are already multiples topics about this on this site, have you tried searching on google with `site:answers.ros.org import service` ?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-21**:
And is this a duplicate of [#q342113](https://answers.ros.org/question/342113/how-to-call-a-service-inside-a-python-node/) ?

**Comment by [ehsan_amp](https://answers.ros.org/users/49314/ehsan_amp/) on 2020-01-21**:
@Delb Thanks for your answer.
Yes, I wanted to call a predefined service as I explained in [#q342113](https://answers.ros.org/question/342113/how-to-call-a-service-inside-a-python-node/). I will write it down as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I Found the problem and each time I compiled the code, it couldn't found the .srv file.
when I wanted to import a service file from another package into a python node, I should first write the package name and the folder name inside that. After that, I use the file name for importing. Like:

```
from dynamixel_controllers.srv import TorqueEnable
```

dynamixel_controller is the name of the package that I want to import file from that and inside the folder srv there is a file named TorqueEnable.

---

Originally posted by [ehsan_amp](https://answers.ros.org/users/49314/ehsan_amp/) with karma: 33 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2